# expand Project Explorer, Package Explorer, or Navigator view from open file in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

Is there a way to expand one of the Project Explorer, Package Explorer, or Navigator views from an open file in Eclipse?

I can see the full path of the opened file in the title bar, but I want to navigate to that location (quickly and automatically) within one of the file structure views. Using Java and JSP in case that matters.

**EDIT :** Reworded: The file is already open. The location of the file in the Project Explorer, Package Explorer, and Navigator views is not open. From the already opened file, can I open the location in one of these views?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you are asking, but I think F3 may be your friend, make sure your cursor is on the class/object reference then just hit f3, should open the file for you. And if you want the project explorer etc to also have the file highlighted make sure you have "Link with editor"(two yellow arrows going in opposite directions) selected in the project explorer etc.

Comment: Maybe I could reword the question. The file is already open. The location of the file in the Project Explorer, Package Explorer, and Navigator views is not open. From the already opened file, can I open the location in one of these views?

Comment: Ah ok, I think I get you, just hit "Link with editor" it will cause the project explorer to show the currently opened file.

Comment: @KevinD, the second part of your answer is the answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On the Package Explorer there is an icon which looks like this: [image: Link With Editor]

Toggling this on will link the tree location from the Package Explorer to the current file in the Editor window.

Comment: you're welcome.  I remember being very happy when I first discovered what this one did ;)

Comment: This is really an awesome feature when you have a large project! I always keep it turned on. :)